# Canon 800D "Movie digital IS" stabilization - cropping video shot?

Tags: canon, video

I am new to DSLR video and wondering, how is actually working "Movie digital IS" stabilization of my Canon 800D. If you shoot video, there are 3 options of IS stabilization - no stabilization, IS stabilization, and IS enhanced stabilization. If i turn on IS stabilization, it looks like it crops the shot (with "IS enhanced" option even more).

So my question is, on what principle is this IS stabilization working and is it lowering the resolution of final shot?

Comment: It is digital stabilization that works similar to stacking multiple still images. The 'ragged edges' that appear in some but not all frames are trimmed from the edges.

Comment: Even after cropping a few pixels from the edge, you should have way more than what is required for 1080p HD video resolution.